# How to pass a pointer to a two-dimensional array whose size is defined by a pointer in C?

Tags: c, struct

I'm working on a project which has multiple input parameters (some of them need to be calculated in the code), so I put all of them in a struct.

```
typedef struct{
    int N_cell;
    int N_node;
}INPUT;
```

In the main function, I declare

```
INPUT in;
```

After that there are several lines used to calculate in.N_cell and in.N_node. Now I define

```
double *pos_node[in.N_node];
for (i = 0; i < in.N_node; i++)
    pos_node[i] = (double *) calloc(3, sizeof(double));
```

Then I need to pass the pointer of this array to a function which I define it as

```
void func(double *pos_node[????]){....}
```

My question is, what should I write in the "????" place? Should I use in.Node and add "INPUT in" in the parameter list?

Thank you so much!

Comment: you'll have a hard time compiling anything like what you have there as you haven't defined a finite size of pos_node (using a variable isn't going to work)

Comment: Do you have some advice on how to deal with this kind of problem? I mean lots of function need to use those input parameters and the size of some arrays are determined by them. Do you think using "extern" variables better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to allocate pos_node on the heap:

```
double **pos_node = calloc(in.N_node, sizeof(double*));
for (i = 0; i < in.N_node; i++)
    pos_node[i] = (double *) calloc(3, sizeof(double));

void func(double **pos_node){....}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to allocate memory for the pos_node as well:

```
double **pos_node = calloc (in.N_node, sizeof (double *));
```

(variable length arrays are available in c99, but most people don't like using c99 yet)

Then it becomes easy to see how to pass the array. An array in C is just a memory block, so `double *array[]` can just as correctly be written as `double **array`: the address of a memory block that holds addresses to doubles.

Comment: You mean when allocate memory for pos_node I should first double **pos_node = calloc (in.N_node, sizeof (double *));  then do    
for (i = 0; i < in.N_node; i++)
    pos_node[i] = (double *) calloc(3, sizeof(double));